# Convert NSDate to NSString with NSDateFormatter with TimeZone without GMT Time Modifier

Tags: objective-c, timezone, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I'm initializing my NSDateFormatter thusly:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

`dateString` is now:

```
Thu, 29 Jul 2010 14:58:42 GMT+00:00
```

I want to get rid of the "+00:00"

I'm guessing from http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Time_Zone_Fallback that I might have a localization issue.  I'm working around this right now by removing the "+00:00" manually, but that isn't ideal.

**EDIT**

I tried a couple of new ways to create the NSTimeZone, but they both produce the same `dateString`:

```
[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
```

Comment: +1 for the interesting question. I can't figure it out myself. BTW, you might want to know about a possible memory leak using the 'z' specifier: http://thegothicparty.com/dev/article/nsdateformatter-memory-leak/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remove the trailing 'z' character from the format string if you don't want to display the time zone.

**EDIT**

On the other hand, if you just want to display the timezone name, just make the 'z' uppercase. ((edit: leave the 'z' lowercase for named timezone, i.e. PST and uppercase 'Z' for -0800))

**EDIT**

Lowercase 'z' works fine for all the other timezones, but unfortunately GMT is a special case. So the easiest thing to do is to just omit the 'z' and append " GMT" to the formatted date.

Comment: The OP wants to keep the time zone abbreviation, but get rid of the +00:00 bit.

Comment: Uppercase 'Z' yields "+0000" per RFC 822 standards.  I just want "GMT"

Comment: Gah, just plain lowercase 'z' works fine for all timezones other GMT, which is a special case. I think the easiest thing to do would be to omit the 'z' and just append " GMT" to the formatted date. It's really annoying that (unless I'm misreading it) the spec doesn't provide a straightforward way to do this.

Comment: That's what I'm doing.  If you edit your answer to reflect your previous statement, I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: Heres a gist, all about the 'z' and 'v' formatters:
https://gist.github.com/rwyland/8683010

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer had a typo.

> > On the other hand, if you just want to display the timezone name, just make the 'z' uppercase.

leave the 'z' lowercase for named timezone, i.e. PST and uppercase 'Z' for -0800

```
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy (EEEE) HH:mm:ss z Z"];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSString *nsstr = [format stringFromDate:now];
```

//January 23, 2013 (Wednesday) 12:33:46 PST -0800