# NSDate being set to the day before

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Important update: Of you hover over a NSDATE with your mouse the degugger will convert the NSDate to your local timezone you have set on you Mac, but if you do a NSLOG you will notice that the NSDate is using the timezone that you assigned to the its respective formatter.

### If you want to see in the xcode debugger what the NSDate is for the timezone you are working with go to your date/time settings for you Mac OS and change the Timezone to the one you are testing.

I require a NSDate to be created from the date I pass in, but currently it is set to the the day before I pass in:

```
 NSString *dateStr = @"2015-08-09";

NSDateFormatter *myformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

The code above returns: an NSDate set to '2015-08-08 12:00:00 +0000'

I need an NSDate object set to the datStr I pass in.

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: If you are going to down-vote please leave a reason why and I will fix or delete the question.

Comment: @Fogmeister Is it possible to get a NSDate irrespective of the timezone?

Comment: NSDate doesn't know anything about time zone. That's why I was asking. NSDate is simply a point in time. It is your computer that converts that point in time to a year, month, date, hour, minute, etc... when you ask it to print the date out using `NSLog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This perhaps, from this:

[Convert NSDate to NSString with NSDateFormatter with TimeZone without GMT Time Modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712140/convert-nsdate-to-nsstring-with-nsdateformatter-with-timezone-without-gmt-time-m)

leave the 'z' lowercase for named timezone, i.e. PST and uppercase 'Z' for -0800

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy (EEEE) HH:mm:ss z Z"];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSString *nsstr = [format stringFromDate:now];
```

Also, you date should be more robust, like if you want to pass in the current day that your are passing in and it's one day off, then just add a day. The problem, it seems is that the date is returning the correct date which is the end of the last day, add 1 second or a millisecond and it'll probably be corrected, or just hack attack this and add 1 day to the days you are passing in. Be smart! Sometimes you just have to add 1 day to fix stuff and move on.

Comment: If the question is answered by an answer to another question, it is a duplicate and should be marked as such.

Comment: surely, but I don't know how this stack stuff works, I've been here for 2 days and I've already answers about a billion questions that you guys couldn't, so feel free to mark it as a duplicate IDGAF. Also, this is clearly a different quesiton, did you read the question? If you didn't I suggest you read it, it's not that many lines and should be easy to digest.

Comment: @daddywarbucks the thought of adding one day seems like a hack solution and I was trying to avoid that, but that did work.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer, I know, I know, but that's just how code works sometimes, I hate doing stuff like this myself, and I get it, but sometimes, it's not worth the trouble, and perhaps you'll have some inspiration after a few hours and think "Ah hah!, I figured it out"

Comment: The format string in your answer doesn't match the string that OP has; there is also a much better way to solve this problem than a "hack attack" so it will "probably be corrected". See the duplicate I've provided.

Comment: My answer is still SOOOOO MUCH better, just add one to stuff and you are done, that's all you do, just add one

Comment: @daddywarbucks it turns out all I needed to do was set the timezone for the formatter and then I found out how the NSDate and xcode debugger work in conjunction with the timezone you have in your Mac OS. If you don't know that the debugger will auto-convert the NSDate time to your local timezone this will cause you the programmer to think they are doing something wrong, which is what happened to me, even after I solved the issue.

Comment: yeah, i assumed it wasn't too hard to do, thanks ConfusedDeer, that helps, adding 1 to stuff randomly is a bad idea unless you have to release your app by tomorrow and you need to code up 5 views still,